# Resource Files not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to java but can find my way around enough to do a bit of simple programming.

I came across this which I thought I'd try (Using IntelliJ 14, Windows 8.1, GeForce graphics card)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/Thisexamplecreatesa3DflyoverofthecityofBoston.htm

After adding all the javax libraries etc the program compiles, but then falls over with this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: heli.obj (The system cannot find the file specified)
Error could not load sound file: javax.media.j3d.SoundException: MediaContainer: setURL - bad URL
```

This appears to be the line where it loads the file

```
protected Group createGeometryGroup( Appearance app, Vector3d position, Vector3d scale, String szTextureFile, String szSoundFile )
    {
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup( );

        // we need to flip the helicopter model
        // 90 degrees about the X axis
        Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D( );
        t3d.rotX( Math.toRadians( -90 ) );
        tg.setTransform( t3d );

        try
        {
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            tg.addChild( loadGeometryGroup( "heli.obj", app ) );
          /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // create an Alpha object for the Interpolator
            Alpha alpha = new Alpha( -1,
                    Alpha.INCREASING_ENABLE | Alpha.DECREASING_ENABLE,
                    (long) Utils.getRandomNumber( 0, 500 ),
                    (long)Utils.getRandomNumber( 0, 500 ),
                    (long)Utils.getRandomNumber( 20000, 5000 ),
                    4000,
                    100,
                    (long) Utils.getRandomNumber( 20000, 5000 ),
                    5000,
                    50 );

            attachSplinePathInterpolator( alpha,
                    new Transform3D( ),
                    new URL( ((Java3dApplet) m_Component).getWorkingDirectory( ), "d:\\flyover\\heli_spline.xls" ) );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.err.println( e.toString( ) );
        }

        return tg;
    }
```

This file and some other resources are in my src directory and get copied to the out directory. So why can't the program find them and where should I put them so they can be found ?

I also tried using a URI "file:///d:/Flyover/heli.obj", but got a "MalformedURL error.

Can anyone help ?

thanks 
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really know what the problem is, but I can speculate that the project you obtained was built under the assumption that the executable will be running in a specific directory, specifically, the directory where heli.obj lives.

They may be explaining this in some readme file somewhere, which you may have missed.

So, you need to leave `loadGeometryGroup( "heli.obj", app )` as is, and you need to go to IntelliJ IDEA's `Run` menu, `Edit Configurations...`, find the configuration of your application in the tree on the left, and specify the `Working Directory` on the right.

Comment: C-:= glad to be of help.  You might want to 'accept' my answer.  (If you had enough reputation you would probably also want to upvote it.)

Comment: I accepted your answer but as this is my first topic, I can't upvote, but thanks for quick reply.